# Solr Spell Check result based filter query

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I implemented Solr SpellCheck Component based on the document from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent , it works good. But i am trying to filter the   **spell check result based on some other filter**. Consider the following schema

```
product_name
product_text
product_category
product_spell -> copy string from product_name and product_text . And tokenized using white space analyzer
```

For the above schema, i am trying to filter the spell check result based on provided category.  I tried querying like http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/colr1/myspellcheck/?q=product_category:160%20appl&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.collate=true . **Spellcheck results does not consider the product_category:160**

Is it because the dictionary was build for all the categories? If so is it a good idea to create the dictionary for every category?

Is it not possible to have another filter condition in spellcheck component?

I am using solr 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I previously understood from the [SOLR-2010](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2010) issue that filtering through the `fq` parameter should be possible using collation, but it isn't, I think I misunderstood.

In fact, the `SpellCheckComponent` has most likely a separate index, except for the `DirectoSolrSpellChecker` implementation. It means the field you select is indexed in a different index, which contains only the information about that specific field you chose to make spelling corrections.

If you're curious, you can also have a look how that additional index looks like using [luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/), since it's of course a lucene index. Unfortunately filtering using other fields isn't an option there, simply because there is only one field there, the one you use to make spelling corrections.

Comment: I wrote on the solr-user mailing list to make sure, but I haven't had a reply yet. Anyway, I had a look at the code, the `fq` parameter is not even read, and I had a look at the index with luke: it doesn't contain enough information to make filters.

Comment: yes according to the index, our finding is correct. please let me know if you get any reply from solr-user mailing list

Comment: Is there any update on this? I'm having the same requirement